# how can i make g++ totally satisfy iso c++ standard

Tags: c++, g++

I am  writing  some simply c++ code to test the c++'s grammer.But when i use g++ to compile it, the result seems to didn't comply  the iso standard.how can i let g++ full of  satisfy iso c++.my code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int s=10;
    int k[s];
    cout<<sizeof(k)/sizeof(int)<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

In the above program ,when  i use the below command to compile it.It did't show any error,while 's' is variable .According to my knowledge ,it should show error.

```
  g++ -Wall -ansi -std=c++11 mytest.cpp.cpp  -o mytest
```

And the result is 10 ,it seems to work good.
Can anyone tell me how can I let g++  show some errors to me .

Comment: Try [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: `g++ -Wall -W -pedantic-errors`